# File system monitor which watches for file/directory changes even after the process is stopped

Tags: python, performance

Building off the python `FileSystemEventHandler` and `DirectorySnapshot` classes, my goal is for a number of projects that I am working on to have a reusable library that will handle file system change notifications while my process is running, but also inform me of any changes that happened while my process was not running.

I implemented my own handler of `DirectorySnapshot` called `DirectorySnapshotFast` that utilizes `os.scandir()` for better performance .08 seconds with `scandir()` vs 15 seconds originally.

I also implemented a blank `EmptyDirectorySnapshot` (borrowed from a StackOverflow user and fixed up as it was not working), so that when no snapshot exists, everything is considered a new file to my program.

I also make sure to keep track of unique path roots - that means that I only monitor the topmost parent of a set of directories. So if it is being asked to monitor `/home` and then `/home/user` is added, it will not monitor for changes in `/home/user` because these will already be emitted by the first monitor.

This is my first *real* python code and I'll be glad to accept any criticism of style, naming, conventions, PEP, performance optimizations, etc.. I will post this on github in case there is any interest as a standalone project.

```
import time
import threading
import pickle
import locale
import os.path
from logger import logging
from event import Event
from os.path import realpath, normcase, sep, normpath
from functools import cmp_to_key
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, FileModifiedEvent, FileCreatedEvent, FileDeletedEvent, FileMovedEvent
from watchdog.utils.dirsnapshot import DirectorySnapshot, DirectorySnapshotDiff

logger = logging.getLogger('watcher')


class DirectorySnapshotFast(DirectorySnapshot):

    def __init__(self, path):
        """Creates a directory snapshot by saving the file paths, inodes and device for every file recursively"""
        self.recursive = True
        self.listdir = None
        self._stat_info = {}
        self._inode_to_path = {}

        st = os.stat(path)
        self._stat_info[path] = st
        self._inode_to_path[(st.st_ino, st.st_dev)] = path

        for e in self.scandirs(path):
            # use the drive letter on windows as st_dev is always 0 unless stat() is called
            if os.name == 'nt':
                i = (e.inode(), self._getdrive(e.path))
            else:
                i = (e.inode(), e.stat().st_dev)

            self._inode_to_path[i] = e.path
            self._stat_info[e.path] = e.stat()

    @staticmethod
    def _getdrive(path):
        drive, tail = os.path.splitdrive(path)
        return drive

    def scandirs(self, top):
        """Recursively scan from the initial directory for all files and directories and return them as a generator"""
        for e in os.scandir(top):
            yield e

            try:
                is_dir = e.is_dir()
            except OSError:
                is_dir = False

            if is_dir:
                yield from self.scandirs(e.path)

    def mtime(self, path):
        """Return the last modified time of a file"""
        return self._stat_info[path].st_mtime


class EmptyDirectorySnapshot(DirectorySnapshot):
    """
    For use as the zeroth snapshot in a chain of DirectorySnapshotDiffs
    """

    def path(self, id):
        return None

    def inode(self, path):
        return None

    def mtime(self, path):
        return None

    @property
    def stat_snapshot(self):
        return {}

    def stat_info(self, path):
        return None

    @property
    def paths(self):
        return set()


# TODO: expire the snapshot after a certain time
# TODO: expire the snapshot if the machine name is different
class FileSystemWatcher(FileSystemEventHandler):
    observers = {}

    # we maintain a list of unique path roots for tracking that we are not trying to watch a sub-directory of a parent
    paths = []
    snapshot_filename = None
    snapshot_secs = 300
    created = Event()
    modified = Event()
    moved = Event()
    deleted = Event()

    def __init__(self, paths=[], snapshot_filename='.snapshot', snapshot_secs=300):
        self.snapshot_secs = snapshot_secs
        self.snapshot_filename = snapshot_filename
        self.paths = list(unique_path_roots(paths))

    def snapshot_timer(self, initial=False):
        """Start a timer that on the sub-sequent call will create snapshots for every monitored directory"""
        if not initial:
            for path in self.paths:
                self.create_snapshot(path)

        t = threading.Timer(self.snapshot_secs, self.snapshot_timer)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def start(self):
        """Process snapshot deltas first, and then setup a file system monitor on them"""
        for path in self.paths:
            snapshot = self.snapshot(path)
            self.write_snapshot(os.path.join(path, self.snapshot_filename), snapshot)
            self.watch(path)

        self.snapshot_timer(initial=True)

    def stop(self):
        """Shutdown the watcher for all paths"""
        for path, observer in self.observers.items():
            self.paths.remove(path)
            observer.stop()

    def watch(self, path):
        """Starts the filesystem watcher on the specified path"""
        if normalize(path) not in self.observers:
            observer = Observer()
            observer.schedule(self, path=path, recursive=True)
            self.observers[normalize(path)] = observer
            observer.start()
            logger.debug('Watching directory: %s', path)

        return self.observers[normalize(path)]

    def snapshot(self, path):
        """Gets the previous snapshot, a new snapshot and compares them to process the deltas"""
        snapshot = self.get_current_snapshot(path)
        current = DirectorySnapshotFast(path)
        self.process_deltas(snapshot, current)
        return current

    def create_snapshot(self, path):
        """Writes a snapshot to the specified path"""
        logger.debug('Creating snapshot file for path: %s', path)
        snapshot_file = os.path.join(path, self.snapshot_filename)
        snapshot = DirectorySnapshotFast(path)
        self.write_snapshot(snapshot_file, snapshot)

        return snapshot

    def write_snapshot(self, snapshot_file, snapshot):
        """Utility for writing the snapshot. Provide a handler/callback to write to sqlite or other in future"""
        with open(snapshot_file, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(snapshot, f)

    def get_current_snapshot(self, path):
        """Get what is considered the previous snapshot, this may be the Empty Snapshot which will only be empty once"""
        snapshot_file = os.path.join(path, self.snapshot_filename)

        # consider the snapshot empty if the file doesn't exist, but create it for the next call
        if not os.path.isfile(snapshot_file):
            snapshot = EmptyDirectorySnapshot(path)
            self.create_snapshot(path)
        else:
            snapshot = self.load_snapshot(snapshot_file)

        return snapshot

    def load_snapshot(self, snapshot_file):
        """Utility to load the snapshot currently from disk, but can be set to sqlite or other in future"""
        with open(snapshot_file, 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)

    @staticmethod
    def snapshot_callback(self, stat_info):
        """Not used."""
        pass

    def process_deltas(self, previous, current):
        """Subtracts current snapshot from previous and calls event handlers for each type of event."""
        delta = current - previous

        for f in delta.files_created:
            self.created(FileCreatedEvent(f))

        for f in delta.files_deleted:
            self.deleted(FileDeletedEvent(f))

        for f in delta.files_modified:
            self.modified(FileModifiedEvent(f))

        for f in delta.files_moved:
            (src, dest) = f
            self.moved(FileMovedEvent(src, dest))

    def add_path(self, path):
        """Adds a path for monitoring."""
        all = set([normalize(path)] + self.paths)
        unique = set(unique_path_roots(all))
        added = unique - set(self.paths)
        removed = set(self.paths) - unique

        # handle removed unique roots first. these roots are now children of a parent that has been added
        for p in removed:
            self.remove_path(p)

        for p in added:
            self.paths.append(normalize(p))
            self.watch(p)

    def remove_path(self, path):
        """Remove the path from monitoring. Either it is no longer requested to be monitored, or it is now a child of a parent"""
        if normalize(path) in self.paths:
            self.paths.remove(normalize(path))

        observer = self.observers.pop(normalize(path), None)
        if observer:
            observer.stop()

    # overriden events for the observer. These are called by the super() class
    def on_moved(self, event):
        self.moved(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.created(event)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.modified(event)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        self.deleted(event)


def normalize(path):
    """Returns a lowercase (Windows) with extra chars removed path"""
    return normcase(normpath(realpath(path)))

def unique_path_roots(paths):
    """Return a list of paths that exclude any children of the parent. For example, c:\\, c:\\users would only return c:\\"""
    visited = set()
    paths = list(set(paths))

    for path in sorted(paths,key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)):
        path = normalize(path)

        head, tail = os.path.split(path)
        while head and tail:
            if head in visited:
                break
            head, tail = os.path.split(head)
        else:
            yield path
            visited.add(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def modded(e):
        print('modified: ', e)

    def added(e):
        print('added: ', e)

    def deld(e):
        print('deleted: ', e)

    def movd(e):
        print('moved: ', e)

    watcher = FileSystemWatcher(paths=["c:\\users\\rayben\\pictures"])
    watcher.modified += modded
    watcher.created += added
    watcher.deleted += deld
    watcher.moved += movd
    watcher.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for path in watcher.paths:
            watcher.create_snapshot(path)
        watcher.stop()
```

Comment: Welcome to codereview! This is a nice first question!

Comment: Thanks! Definitely would like a look over before I release it, and being that I probably don't know the full feature set of python yet, there are probably better ways to do some of the things that I am doing. Looking for tips.

Comment: The way that you're using `print` indicates that you're primarily using Python 3. Are you targeting both Python 2 and Python 3, or a specific version of 3 and above?

Comment: Only Python3 (and more specifically only ones that contain scandir()). If there is interest I could go back and change it, but it wouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: I was just wondering if I had an excuse to try out the new [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library, ;P BTW [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) is 3.5+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to review the `DirectorySnapshotFast` class.

1. There's no docstring for the class. What kind of thing is a `DirectorySnapshotFast` object? How is it different from a `DirectorySnapshot` object? Something to do with a faster implementation and different treatment of drives on Windows, but what exactly?
2. The `__init__` method sets `recursive` and `listdir` attributes that are not used.
3. In the `_inode_to_path` dictionary you have different behaviour on Windows (using the drive letter) and non-Windows (using the device number) — except that for the original `path` you always use the device number. This seems to be a bug.
4. I have to confess that I don't understand the purpose of the different behaviour on Windows. A `DirectorySnapshot` object caches information about the files *in a directory* — and so all these files will have the same drive letter on Windows. But maybe there is something I missed? There needs to be an explanation somewhere of what problem is being solved here.
5. The test `os.name == 'nt'` is repeated for each directory `e`, but the result of this test is not going to change. Consider caching the result of this test in a local variable.
6. In the non-Windows case `e.stat()` is called twice for each entry. Consider caching this in a local variable.
7. The `_getdrive` method is called from only one place and is just one line long. I suggest inlining it at the point of use.
8. The `scandirs` method is only called from within `__init__`, so could be declared locally to that function (compare the implementation of [`DirectorySnapshot.__init__`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/blob/master/src/watchdog/utils/dirsnapshot.py#L200), where `walk` is declared locally.
9. [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) is a broad class of exceptions — consider catching just the exception that you want to ignore (presumably [`PermissionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PermissionError)).
10. The `mtime` method implementation is identical to the [corresponding implemetation](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/blob/master/src/watchdog/utils/dirsnapshot.py#L263) in the `DirectorySnapshot` class. There is no need to repeat this in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks, I will be reworking the code as suggested. Right now I am stuck because there is a 'bug' in Py3.5 where the os.DirEntry object is not accessible. It was fixed in 3.6 but I am unable to move up at this point, so have to redo a couple of pieces of code.

I don't necessarily agree with #5 but it will become a moo point with the rework anyway. As for #9 it has to be OSError because there are many reasons you may not have access to the file at the time (permission, locked, deleted/moved after opening it, etc..)

Comment: @esac: Any thoughts on #4? I'm curious as to your reasoning here.

Comment: Sorry been travelling. I am basing it off the original implementation, so my only assumption is that if you follow symlinks, the file can actually reside on a different device/drive. I am going to test that out soon, just waiting for some time to sit down and rework all of your suggestions.